# routes.MapPageRoute for infinite category url

Tags: routes, url-routing

I'm using Asp.net C# webform , framework 4.
I need to have a routes.MapPageRoute rule to show category url like:
http://localhost/digital/mobile/asus
I saved **digital/mobile/asus** as url of category in Database.

Is use this code:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
            "catmain-Rout",
            "{id}",
            "~/cat.aspx"
            );
```

but whe I use **/** in url like **digital/mobile/asus** , 404 eror happens!
whats the solution?
tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used * for **cath it all**.

```
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "category-Rout",
            "{*id}",
            "~/category.aspx"
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

you would use

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
            "catmain-Rout",
            "{category}/{sub_category}/{id}",
            "~/cat.aspx"
            );
```

so in your case:

```
category = digital
sub_category = mobile
id = asus
```

and retrieve the relevant information as required based on these parameters.

Post more code for a better answer...

Comment: "asus" is not an id, its a category

Comment: really doesnt matter. name the variables in parenthesis as you want. more info on routing here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: I have infinite category. it mighte look like this: site.com/maincat/cat1/cat2/cat3/cat4/cat5/.....